# Can't get Scrapy Crawlspider to follow links

Tags: python, regex, screen-scraping, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to get the 'Rules' section of a Scrapy Crawlspider working properly.

I've found the `xpath` that returns the links I want to follow. It's

```py
//*[@class="course_detail"]//td[4]/a/@href
```

and it returns about 2700 URL's in total.

Basically, I'm trying to tell the spider to follow everything that matches that `xpath`, but I can't get the following code to work properly:

```
rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor( allow=[r'.*'],
                            restrict_xpaths='//*[@class="course_detail"]//td[4]/a/@href'
                           ),              
         callback='parse_item'
         ),
)
```

I don't get any errors, but the spider doesn't seem to get past the page I defined in `start_urls`.

EDIT: Figured it out! Just had to drop the @href. Hayden's code helped too so I'm awarding  him with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `allow` and `restrict_xpaths` ought to be of the same type (i.e. either both list or both strings) when passing to [SgmlLinkExtractor](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#sgmllinkextractor). Most examples use `tuples`:

```
rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor( allow = (r'.*',),
                            restrict_xpaths = ('//*[@class="course_detail"]//td[4]/a/@href',)
                           ),              
         callback='parse_item'
         ),
)
```

*As an aside a like to use [Egyptian Brackets](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html) to try and keep track of where my arguments.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hayden! Unfortunately I'm still having the same problem :(